# Insert Spark Dataset[(String, Map[String, String])] to Cassandra Table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, nosql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a Spark Dataset of type Dataset[(String, Map[String, String])].

I have to insert the same into a Cassandra table.

Here, key in the Dataset[(**String**, Map[String, String])] will become my primary key of the row in Cassandra.

The Map in the Dataset[(String, **Map[String, String]**)] will go in the same row in a column **ColumnNameValueMap**.

The Dataset can have millions of rows.

I also want to do it in optimum way (e.g. batch insert Etc.)

My Cassandra table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleKeyspace.CassandraTable (
  RowKey text PRIMARY KEY,
  ColumnNameValueMap map<text,text>
);
```

Please suggest how to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that you need is just to use [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/doc) (better to take version 2.5.0 that was just released). It provides read & write functions for datasets, so in your case it will be just

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
your_data.write.cassandraFormat("CassandraTable", "SampleKeyspace").mode("append").save()
```

If your table don't exist yet, then [you can create it base don the structure of the dataset itself](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#creating-a-new-cassandra-table-from-a-dataset-schema) - there are 2 functions: `createCassandraTable` & `createCassandraTableEx` - it's better to use 2nd, as it provides more control over table creation.

P.S. You can find more about 2.5.0 release in the following [blog post](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all).

Comment: Let me try this. Will the Cassandra table structure and my Dataset match automatically?

Comment: Yes, it worked. One new issue I am facing: I am updating the same map column (2nd column) with new key values for the same rowkey (1st column/primary key). But, every new update to this column purges the previous map. How can I append the same map using Spark Cassandra connector? If you want I can create another question for you. Please suggest.

Comment: yeah, it's better to make it as a separate question, and don't have everything in comments

Comment: Posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953869/update-map-type-columns-in-cassandra-with-new-key-value-pairs-and-not-completely. Please suggest.