# Update Map type columns in Cassandra with new key value pairs and not completely overwrite the map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Continuing the question at [Insert Spark Dataset[(String, Map[String, String])] to Cassandra Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61946840/insert-spark-datasetstring-mapstring-string-to-cassandra-table).

I have a Spark Dataset of type Dataset[(String, Map[String, String])].

I have to insert the same into a Cassandra table.

Here, key in the Dataset[(String, Map[String, String])] will become my primary key of the row in Cassandra.

The Map in the Dataset[(String, Map[String, String])] will go in the same row in a column ColumnNameValueMap.

My Cassandra table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleKeyspace.CassandraTable (
  RowKey text PRIMARY KEY,
  ColumnNameValueMap map<text,text>
);
```

I was able to insert the data in Cassandra table using the Spark Cassandra connector.

**Now, I am updating the same map column (2nd column) with new key values for the same rowkey (1st column/primary key). But, every new update to this column purges the previous map.**

***How can I append the same map using Spark Cassandra connector?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to do it directly from Dataframe API, but i[t's possible to do via RDD API](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#modifying-cql-collections). For example, I have following tabble with some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE test.m1 (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    m map<int, text>
);
cqlsh> select * from test.m1;                                                                                                                                                                                                  id | m                                                                                                        ----+--------------------                                                                                        1 | {1: 't1', 2: 't2'}                                                                                                                                                                                                      (1 rows)
```

and I have data in Spark:

```
scala> val data = Seq((1, Map(3 -> "t3"))).toDF("id", "m")                                                     data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, m: map<int,string>]
```

then I can specify that I want to append data to specific column wit following code:

```
data.rdd.saveToCassandra("test", "m1", SomeColumns("id", "m" append))
```

and I can see that data is updated:

```
cqlsh> select * from test.m1;
id | m
----+----------------------------- 
 1 | {1: 't1', 2: 't2', 3: 't3'}
(1 rows)
```

Besides `append`, there is support for removing elements with `remove` option, and `prepend` (only for lists).  Documentation contains examples on that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did the same before your answer. I was expecting a dataframe support from you :). Anyways, thanks for all the help. Have upvoted and accepted the answer.

Comment: You  can file JIRA... Maybe it will be implemented fast enough...

Comment: btw., if you have only one collection column, then instead you can change data model instead - to `create table test(partition_key text, map_key text, value text, primary key(partition_key, map_key));` - it will work the same as with map, but you'll able to select individual values easier, and have less overhead

Comment: This one is increasing the size of my output from spark job to be written to cassandra by many folds. I finallly reverted my code to use Dataset[(String, Map(String, String)], it reduces the output size. Why does it increase the data size in your commented solution? I had found one blog on the net for this but not finding that again.